# Is the verb "went" necessary?

Tags: verbs, descriptive-grammar

I wrote [the following sentence at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob's_Big_Boy#Bob_Wian_before_Big_Boy) concerning Bob Wian who later founded the Big Boy restaurant chain:

> His father's furniture business bankrupt, Wian washed dishes in the school cafeteria to pay for lunch.

Another editor made this correction adding "went", which I see as unnecessary:

> His father's furniture business **went** bankrupt, Wian washed dishes in the school cafeteria to pay for lunch.

(If a verb would be necessary, it is "having gone" or "being", not "went".)

In my sentence the word "being" is implied but not need be written as it seems to weight the sentence down.

> His father's furniture business **being** bankrupt, Wian washed dishes in the school cafeteria to pay for lunch.

I could write the sentence (which isn't much different from the original):

> His father's furniture business **now** bankrupt, Wian washed dishes in the school cafeteria to pay for lunch.

But the original sentence feels right. Less is more. Opinions?

[image: Less is more — Mies van de Rohe]

Comment: You can use the "edit" button to fix the title.

Comment: As for the grammar of the Wikipedia entry, I believe you are correct, and the edited version is incorrect, but I think what is needed is a rewrite that is both correct _and_ easy for anyone to understand. Not every reader will be as literate as you.

Comment: There are several ways to handle this, none of which include the editor's making matters worse. I'd do this: Now that his father's furniture business was bankrupt, Wian began washing dishes in the school cafeteria to pay for his lunch.

Comment: Adding the word _went_ makes the sentence completely ungrammatical. Your original sentence is fine. Lambie’s suggestion is equally fine, but less likely to lead less competent readers astray. Another option could be “With his father’s furniture business now bankrupt, Wian washed/was forced to wash dishes in the school cafeteria to pay for lunch”.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Although I reverted the sentence, I'm now liking KarlG's _after-went_ construction, which reads to a wider audience, is efficient, and will make the other editor's edit constructive. You know (writing on this topic for Wikipedia), I've noticed how sloppy writing by newspaper hacks perpetuates and evolves into misinformation. And I speak of mainstream papers in major US cities. I don't want my published writing to take that course. Thank you for you assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*His father's furniture bankrupt* is a perfectly acceptable, though increasingly rare construction known as a [nominative absolute.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute) Inserting a *went* without further revision (*after* in the beginning or a *so* introducing the main clause) turns your sentence into a grammatical mess.

Making the temporal or causative relationship explicit between bankruptcy and dishwashing weakens rather than strengthens your sentence.